# Why is AND a macro in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

As the title say: Why is `and` a macro instead of a function?
I was trying to apply and to list and got an error, after some searching, I found I should do something like `(every #'identify list)` instead.

but now I wonder why `and` is a macro and I can't find any good explanation.

Comment: Because if it was a function it would have always evaluated all of its arguments, which is clearly not the semantics you want from an `and`.

Comment: Ofcourse, when you say it like that, it is so obvious :-) . Why not write an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Sometimes the semantics you want from `and` is really just Boolean logic. I maintain a Lisp dialect in which `and` is a macro as well as a function. So if you want to map two lists of Boolean values through `and`, it works just fine.  Common Lisp doesn't allow `and` to have a binding as a macro/operator and function at the same time. A choice has to be made whether `and` is a function or macro.  The evaluation control aspect of `and` is essential a lot of the time, and so since functions are strict call-by-value, macro it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine this function:

```
(defun my-every (predicate list)
  (or (null list)  
      (and (funcall predicate (car list))
           (my-every predicate (cdr list)))))
```

If `and` or `or` were functions this function would always be a infinite loop. This uses both the fact that `or` and `and` short circuits. Eg if `list` is `nil` then the whole thing is `t` and no further processing is done. If `(funcall predicate (car list))` is `nil` then that is the result since `and` short circuits false.

In fact both `or` and `and` may be implemented using `if` so one could just as well written it like this:

```
(defun my-every (predicate list)
  (if (null list)
      T  
      (if (funcall predicate (car list))
          (my-every predicate (cdr list))
          NIL)))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Logical Operator and Control Structure**

`and` is by definition and design both a *control structure* and a *logical operator*.

Logical operators like `and` and `or` are also useful control structures. Thus they can't be a function, because then all the arguments would be evaluated before the operator gets called. One would need to define them either as *built-in operator* or as a function. Common Lisp by design has a minimum number of *built-in operators* and the `and`/`or` functionality can be provided by a macro, which expands into other constructs like ... thus it was chosen that those be macros.

`CLtL2` describes it this way:

> To put it another way, the `and` special form does short-circuit Boolean evaluation, like the `and then` operator in Ada and what in some Pascal-like languages is called `cand` (for *conditional and*); the Lisp and special form is unlike the Pascal or Ada `and` operator, which always evaluates both arguments.

Slight mistake in the text: `(and ...)` is not a special form, but a macro form.